# Is there any way to see the diff on a file between two different Android releases?

Tags: android, git

It would be really nice if there is some easy way to see what have changed in a certain class (or other file) between two releases (1.6 & 2.1 for example). Does anyone know how to do this?

A way to do it online would be great but downloading the code and checking offline would be ok as well.

Comment: are we talking about the APIs from the SDK?

Comment: No I was looking for a diff on the source code.

Comment: By *'online'* did you mean using gitweb?  Could you provide link to gitweb for the project you are interested in?

Comment: Here is an online version of the git:
http://android.git.kernel.org/

I can use the above one to look at the source code and see diffs for a specific commit (ex: http://bit.ly/9NVfy8) but I would like to see diffs between releases. 

All releases are saved as tags if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

you tagged this question with git, so with git it would be:

```
git diff 1.6..2.1 -- path/to/classfile
```

Comment: assuming the android people tag their release commits -- edit: they do, e.g. http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/esd.git;a=tags

Answer (score 1):

To see a comprehensive, auto-generated list of differences between API levels, see the diff reports:

- http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/7/changes.html
- http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/6/changes.html
- ...

Comment: Yeah I've seen those before and they are quite useful but this time I need a diff on the source code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's easier way then heading to https://android.googlesource.com and browsing to your file on different heads then downloading it to your drive and comparing them manually.